# How to verify signed XML file in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, saml, signature

I am trying to verify a signed XML document. The XML document is signed with a 509 Certificate.

I already wrote the code in C#, but I don't know how to do the translation to VB.NET

Here is my code in C#:

```
public static Boolean VerifyXmlFile(XmlDocument Doc, X509Certificate2 Cert)
        {
            // Check the arguments.  
            if (Doc == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Doc");


            // Create a new SignedXml object and pass it the XML document class.
            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(Doc);

            try
            {
                // Find the "Signature" node and create a new XmlNodeList object.
                XmlNodeList nodeList = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("ds:Signature");

                // Load the signature node.
                signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

                // Check the signature and return the result.
                return signedXml.CheckSignature(Cert, true);
            }
            catch
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Error verifying the signature!" + Environment.NewLine);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I just need this code but in VB.NET

Comment: This isn't a code conversion service.  Try https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can just let it through an online converter, e.g. this one here:

http://converter.telerik.com

The result is something like this, and as far as I can say there are no issues with that code:

```
Public Shared Function VerifyXmlFile(ByVal Doc As XmlDocument, ByVal Cert As X509Certificate2) As Boolean
    If Doc Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("Doc")
    Dim signedXml As SignedXml = New SignedXml(Doc)
    Try
        Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("ds:Signature")
        signedXml.LoadXml(CType(nodeList(0), XmlElement))
        Return signedXml.CheckSignature(Cert, True)
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Maybe replace the parameter names through lower-case ones and instead of hard-coding the name of the `ArgumentNullException("Doc")` you could use `ArgumentNullException(NameOf(Doc))`. Or instead of `Dim signedXml As SignedXml = New SignedXml(Doc)` use `Dim signedXml As New SignedXml(Doc)` but that's just cosmetic...